# How do I get the channel_id of a channel in discord?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot using node.js. I want the bot to send a welcome message. At the moment I copied the channel_id of the the welcome channel from discord. Though I want to write code to get the id of the welcome channel by its name. (Or if there is another more effective method). Using discord.js v13.

Comment: You can use `client.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0])` if i remember to use the channel id instead of pinging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the channel from cache by using `Guild#channels`. That includes a `cache` property which has all the channels the bot can see in it<sup>[1]</sup>. Use the `find()` method on it and compare the name

```js
// remember channel names can only be lowercase and have no spaces
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name");
console.log(channel.id)
```

One drawback here is that multiple channels can have the same name, unlike IDs, which is why people prefer using IDs instead of name or other properties

<sup>[1]: All channels are cached by default, so no need to fetch from API</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Fetch** the channels of the guild and then find in the cache by its name

```js
<Guild>.channels.fetch().then(channels => channels.cache.find(c=> c.name === "channel_name_here"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Guild.channels` to get the list of `channel`s in the server, then loop through them using [the `fetch()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) to find a `channel` with a matching name.